# Windows Forms - How to break execution of currently executing code

Tags: c#, winforms, return, execution

I have an abstract windows form called **AddEditReminderForm** containing, amongst others, an event handler and a method:

1. buttonSave_Click
2. PerformValidations

Here is the relevant code for **AddEditReminderForm**:

```
protected virtual void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    title = textboxTitle.Text;
    description = textboxDescription.Text;
    place = textboxPlace.Text;
    date = datePicker.Value.Date;
    time = timePicker.Value.TimeOfDay;

    PerformValidations();
}

protected void PerformValidations()
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: The title field was left empty!");
        return;
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(description))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: The description field was left empty!");
        return;
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(place))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: The place field was left empty!");
        return;
    }

    if (date < currentDate)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: The date must be in the future!");
        return;
    }

    if (date == currentDate && time < currentTime)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: The time must be in the future!");
        return;
    }
}
```

I then have a form called **AddReminderForm** which inherits from **AddEditReminderForm**.  I am overriding the **buttonSave_Click** event handler such that it saves the reminder in addition to the normal operations that it performs in the base class.  Here is the code for the **AddReminderForm**:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Reminder.Classes;

namespace Reminder
{
    public partial class AddReminderForm : AddEditReminderForm
    {
        public AddReminderForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = "Add Reminder Form";

            Label labelFormHeading = this.Controls["labelFormHeading"] as Label;
            labelFormHeading.Text = "Add Reminder";
        }

        protected override void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.buttonSave_Click(sender, e);
            AddReminderOperation();
        }

        protected void AddReminderOperation()
        {
            ReminderClass reminder = new ReminderClass();
            reminder.Id = ReminderHelper.GetCounter();
            reminder.Title = title;
            reminder.Description = description;
            reminder.Place = place;
            reminder.Date = date;
            reminder.Time = time;

            ReminderHelper.AddReminder(reminder);
            MessageBox.Show("The reminder has been successfully saved!");
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the problem that I have is that, when the **AddReminderForm** is open, in case one of the validations in the **PerformValidations** method fails, the message box is shown but execution is not stopped and the reminder is still saved.  How can I break execution if one of the validation fails please?  I am using return, but if I remember correctly, return only stops the execution of the current method.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a method in your base class, `ValidateAndSave`, which is called form the event handler:

```
protected void ValidateAndSave()
{
    if (this.PerformValidations())
    {
        this.Save();
    }
}

private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ValidateAndSave();
}

protected bool PerformValidations()
    /* could be virtual, if you want to do additional checks in derived classes */
{ ... }

protected virtual void Save()
{ ... }
```

You let `PerformValidations` return `true` if all validations are okay. Then call save, which you can override in the deriving classes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the approach you described.  It makes a lot of sense.  Thanks.